# Can you use your local CPU and Google Colab's GPU at the same time?

Tags: python, gpu, google-colaboratory, cpu, torch

I'm running some notebooks which, at different points, are both CPU and GPU intensive. Running the notebook on my local PC is fast in terms of CPU power, but slow as my GPU cannot be used for Torch (I have a Ryzen 9 with an AMD GPU). On the other hand, running the notebook on the Colab GPU is fast in the GPU sections, but terribly slow in the CPU sections.

I know that it is possible to use my CPU using local runtime, but then I am also stuck with my local GPU. Is it possible to allocate *only* my local CPU and use the Google colab GPU at the same time?

(An alternative solution would be to run the CPU intensive code on my local machine, store the intermediate results, and then use the Google GPU for the GPU intensive parts. But this is of course sub optimal.)

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge, you can distribute training among multiple GPUs, multiple machines, or TPUs with a built-in distribution strategy.

The `MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy` is the one you are looking for most likely. It has two implementations for cross-device communications. Most of all, CommunicationImplementation.RING is RPC-based and supports both CPU and GPU.

Details: [Link 1](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training) [Link 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/experimental/CommunicationImplementation#RING)